# Macro que atualiza uma linha após a outra com textos em duas celulas - Excel/VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Basicamente quero uma macro que sempre que eu clico no botão associado a ela, essa macro me produz 2 textos que ficarão em duas celulas. Em seguida a medida que eu clico eessa macro preenche os mesmos textos a cada linha abaixo da anterior.

- No primeiro clique, o primeiro texto "Texto - 1" irá ficar na celula `D4` e outro texto "Texto-2" na celula `I4` simultaneamente.
- Aí, eu clico de novo nesse botão ele inclui o primeiro texto na celula `D5` e o segundo texto na celula `I5`
- Quando eu clicar pela terceira vez, novamente, o texto "Texto-1" irá ficar na celula `D6` e outro texto "Texto-2" na celula `I6` simultaneamente.

Eu vou sempre preenchendo a cada linha. Uma abaixo da outra.

Espero que tenha ficado clara a minha pergunta. Pq qualquer coisa eu edito.

Abaixo esta o codigo para o primeiro clique. Tudo funciona bem. Mas quando clico pela segunda vez ele não atualiza nas linhas abaixo.

```
Sub macro_1()
    Range("D4") = "Texto-1"
    Range("I4") = "Texto-2"
    Range("D5").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

O movimento para a célula "abaixo" pode ser feito com o método [Offset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) do
objeto Range.

Acredito que a dificuldade para desenvolver esta macro é "descobrir" qual é a
última célula preenchida na coluna.

Um caminho para executar esta operação manualmente, é selecionar a
primeira célula da coluna (ex: "D4"), depois é digitar a seqüencia
de teclas:

**END + SETA PARA BAIXO**

Porém, desta forma, só funciona após as duas primeiras células estarem preenchidas
(ex: a partir da célula "D6"), caso contrário, o END+DOWN irá "parar" no final da
planilha.

Para desenvolver a macro, uma possibilidade é utilizar a mesma lógica.

Abaixo, segue o código comentado explicando a lógica para executar a
operação da forma descrita acima, mas existem outras formas para
desenvolver a mesma funcionalidade.

*Dica*: para macros simples, é mais fácil você "gravar" a macro ou uma parte
dela manualmente e depois, analisar o código-fonte que o Excel gerou e
alterá-lo conforme a sua necessidade. Assim, você não perde muito tempo
consultando a documentação.

```vba
Option Explicit

Rem ****************************************
Rem Testa se o endereço informado é válido
Rem na planilha ativa
Rem ****************************************
Private Function EnderecoInvalido(endereco As String) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    
    Rem Tentar selecionar um range. Caso ele não exista
    Rem ou seja inválido, Err.Number irá retornar um valor
    Rem diferente de 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(endereco).Select
    EnderecoInvalido = Err.Number = 0
End Function

Rem ****************************************
Rem Preenche as colunas
Rem ****************************************
Private Sub PreencheColuna(endereco As String, valor As String)

    Rem Testa se o range informado é válido (função acima) e
    Rem mostra alert com erro, caso não seja
    If EnderecoInvalido(endereco) Then
        Call MsgBox("Endereço Inválido", vbCritical, "Endereço Inválido")
    End If
    
    Rem Seleciona o range
    Range(endereco).Select
    
    Rem Se a célula já estiver preenchida...
    If Not (IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)) Then
        Rem ...testa se a célula abaixo está vazia.
        Rem Este procedimento é feito apenas para a segunda
        Rem célula abaixo.
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        Else
            Rem Move a seleção para a última célula preenchida abaixo
            Range(endereco).End(xlDown).Select
            Rem Move a seleção para a próxima célula vazia (abaixo)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        End If
    End If
    
    Rem Preenche a célula com o valor
    ActiveCell.Value = valor
End Sub

Rem ****************************************
Rem Ponto de entrada da macro (público)
Rem ****************************************
Public Sub InsereTexto()
    Rem Trata a coluna D
    Call PreencheColuna("D4", "Texto-1")
    
    Rem Trata a coluna I
    Call PreencheColuna("I4", "Texto-2")
End Sub
```